# SVM: How do I use the chi2 kernel in vlfeat

Tags: matlab, svm, chi-squared, vlfeat

I would like to use the chi2 kernel instead of the linear kernel in vlfeat.

[Here](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/svm.html) is an example of using chi2.

"...
% create a structure with kernel map parameters
**hom.kernel = 'KChi2';

hom.order = 2;**

% create the dataset structure
**dataset = vl_svmdataset(X, 'homkermap', hom);**

% learn the SVM with online kernel map expansion using the dataset structure
**[w b info] = vl_svmtrain(dataset, y, lambda, 'MaxNumIterations', maxIter)**..."

What exactly happens here? What does hom.order do?

What does vl_svmdataset do?
Also, there is a function called vl_homkermap(). What does it do?

Let's say I got a matrix m and I would like to use svm on it with the chi2 kernel.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Large scale non-linear support vector machines (SVMs) can be approximated by linear ones using a suitable feature map.
The linear SVMs are in general much faster to learn and evaluate (test) than the original non-linear, you may consult to [this](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vedaldi/assets/pubs/vedaldi11efficient.pdf) paper for the detail.

> dataset = vl_svmdataset(X, 'homkermap', hom);
>    this line transform your data X to the 'chi-square' kernel map
>
> [w b info] = vl_svmtrain(dataset, y, lambda, 'MaxNumIterations', maxIter)
>    this line train a linear SVM for the transformed data in this case lambda is regularization parameter more detail can be find 
>   [here](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_svmtrain.html)